# How to change only the home page / front page url on wordpress

Tags: pages, urls, homepage

i want to change only the url/permalink of the home page for example like this

mysite.com to mysite.com/blog .

Guys don't think i am a noob, i know that there is the option on wordpress dashboard Settings/General Site Address (URL), but that changes the url for all site posts, categories, tags etc.
I want to change the link just for the home page, nothing else.
I also tried to set a static front page but still the url/permalink didn't change for the home page.

It wil be great if anybody can help!

Answer (score 1):

have you tried the "quick edit" button on the WordPress page admin area? You can change the slug there but I am not certain that's what you are looking to do.

Actually, sorry. I tried this myself, you can change the slug but it's not showing the change in my local environment when I navigate to my own home/front page. I was going to delete this but maybe it will help somehow.

Comment: Thanks but that's not the solution. I need another way to do what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In the admin panel of WordPress, you have the option to set your blog page as your home page under Settings > general > home page.
If it is a blog you are after.

Maybe this can be a solution for you.

Comment: But you still can't change the permalink, all i want is to change the url/permalink of the home page.

Comment: Ok, you can redirect using .htaccess file but I advise against it (SEO reasons) if you are familiar with Javascript you can append a suffix to your URL

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/ have a look at this, it may be of use